# Conda environment wrong pyyaml version

Tags: python-3.x, conda, pyyaml

`conda list pyyaml`

```
# packages in environment at c:\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyyaml                    3.13            py36hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
```

`conda env list`

```
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\Anaconda3
base                     c:\Anaconda3
yaml                  *  c:\Anaconda3\envs\yaml
```

Switching to yaml environment 
`activiate yaml`

`conda list pyyaml`

```
# packages in environment at c:\Anaconda3\envs\yaml:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyyaml                    5.2              py36he774522_0
```

Starting Python within environment yaml with `python`

```
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__version__
'3.13'
```

Why is 3.13 and not 5.2 returned?

Update 2019-12-17, 14:32

```
(base) D:\a\buch>
(base) D:\a\buch>conda activate yaml
(yaml) D:\a\buch>
(yaml) D:\a\buch>python
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__version__
'3.13'
>>>
(yaml) D:\a\buch>c:\Anaconda3\envs\yaml\python.exe
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__version__
'3.13'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in anaconda by default you will be in the base environment where the version of `pyyaml` is 3.13(in your case).

If you activate the environment `yaml` and check the version of `pyyaml`, you will find the 5.2 version of `pyyaml`

The problem in your case is that you are in the same base environment. Kindly use the following command to switch to the other environment.

```
conda activate yaml
```

You forgot to use the conda command before `activate yaml` hence you are in the same base environment.

Kindly follow this [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) also.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I undestand, but what do I have to do to get 5.2 in my python repl?

Comment: Just see my update from 14:32... maybe the problem is sitting in front of the keyboard...